# Uploading File with okhttp 3.9.0 to REST is giving Error code=422, message=Uprocessable Entity

Tags: java, okhttp

I'm trying to upload a file to a REST-Service via okhttp3 (3.9.0).

It does not work and I got the error: ** code=422, message=Unprocessable Entity**
but I can't find my error ...

Here is my code:

```
private void test_OK_HTTP() {

        String userCredentials = "username:password";
        String basicAuth = "Basic " + new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(userCredentials.getBytes()));

        File f = new File("C:\\history48.png");
       
      
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
                .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                .addFormDataPart("DocumentName", "file.png")
                .addFormDataPart("FK_Person", "1d64b9cc-d405-47c4-9adb-ef276c391ae0&")
                .addFormDataPart("FK_FileManagerFormKey", "33")
                .addFormDataPart("SystemFileType", "368")
                .addFormDataPart("Subject", "test")
                .addFormDataPart("SubjectDate", "2022-02-24")
                .addFormDataPart("DocumentContent", "file.png", RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/png"), f))                                    
                .build();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("http://myurlthatworksfine/RestServiceTest/AddNewDocument")
                .addHeader("api-version", "v1")
                .addHeader("Authorization", basicAuth)
                .post(requestBody)            
                .build();
        
        System.out.println("Request: "+request.body().toString());

        try {
            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            System.out.println("Response: " + response.toString());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Error: "+e);
        }

    }
```

Has any one any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had a simple error in my test-id ... it works now ... :)

WRONG:
.addFormDataPart("FK_Person", "1d64b9cc-d405-47c4-9adb-ef276c391ae0&")

OK:
.addFormDataPart("FK_Person", "1d64b9cc-d405-47c4-9adb-ef276c391ae0")